# Как выйти из рекурсии и сохранить результат в C#

Tags: c#

Суть такова что я делаю метод и в нем вызываю еще раз этот метод чтобы зациклить до условий if.
как только if true, у меня идет return result(число) все бы хорошо
но следом у меня идет вызов рекурсивного метода после которого тоже стоит return result и когда стек вызовов очищается то у меня мой результат возвращается к исходному, а я хочу возвращать результат до выхода из рекурсии и очищения стека.

```
    static double Calculate(double money, double percent, int month)
    {
        double peremennaya = money * (percent/100); // через 12 мес было бы
        double monthmoney = (peremennaya / 12) + money; //через первый месяц будет
        money = monthmoney;  // обновляем
        month--;

        double result = money;
        if (month <= 0)
            return result; // хочу вывести это
      
            Calculate(money, percent, month);

            return result; //а выводится это
     }
```

нужно было так сделать:

```
double result = money;
            if (month <= 0)
                return result;

             result = Calculate(money, percent, month);
               
                    return result;
```

Comment: Возможно вы просто не меняете `result`...?

Comment: к сожалению, такой вопрос без кода, это гадания на кофейной гуще

Comment: Вы можете присвоить результат в поле, например или в коллекцию по ссылке. Нужен код.

Comment: Так может нужно делать `return Calculate(money, percent, month);`, нет?